# Is there a way for a Jenkins Pipeline, in a Multibranch setup, to automatically checkout the branch that is at the latest revision?

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to configure job in Jenkins Multibranch pipeline. There are a lot of branches in SVN  and I want the job to checkout only the latest one and ignores the rest of them. This job triggers a pipeline that does multiple checks on the whole build... so I always need to trigger this on the latest branch because there I will have the latest revision of the build.

The SVN structure is like this: V01_01_01 till the latest one V01_08_03. Currently I have it set up like the below and in the Jenkins pipeline I have "checkout scm", but if a new branch appears e.g. V01_08_04 I need V01_08_03 to be replaced by V01_08_04. Is there any way to do this ?

My set-up in Jenkins Multibranch pipeline

[image: My set-up in Jenkins Multibranch pipeline]

Comment: From Jenkins/git point of view, there's no relation whatsoever between branches named `V01_08_03` and `V01_08_04`. One is not a "better/later/more updated" version of another. You may want to run your job on all branches, understand what branch you're running on, get a list of all branches, and if a "better" version exist, refuse to continue with your job.

Comment: tx @MaratC, you are right! I changed the setup to include all branches: in "Include branches" I added " /* " and in "Exclude branches" I added the rest except the one I need so in case a new one appears it will be added automatically by the "Multibranch". I was thinking that maybe there is a way to identify the latest one based on revision number somehow... the highest revision should be the latest one...

Comment: As mentioned, there's no "latest" and no "revision number" and no "highest" in the names of git branches. The comparison operation over the branches names is not defined. You may want to solve it by having a special name for whatever branch you deem latest, and merge into it once a newer version rolls out. While there, you may want to name it e.g. `master`.

Comment: you are keep addressing Git yet I mentioned in the post and as you can see in the pic I am using Subversion where we have revision numbers...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Subversion or the way it works, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a hack to this. I created a python script that checks the whole repository for the latest folder that was updated.

```
    pipeline
{
    agent any
    parameters
    {
        string(name: 'latest_folder', defaultValue: '')
    }
    stages
    {
        stage ('find latest folder')
        {
            steps
            {
                withPythonEnv('System-CPython-3.8')
                {
                    sh 'pip3 install svn'
                    script {
                        def folder_name = sh(script: 'python3 latest_folder_svn.py', returnStdout: true)
                        env.latest_folder = folder_name
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage ('Checkout Step')
        {
            steps
            {
                echo "${env.latest_folder}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This variable I will add it in the checkout step in order to have always the latest branch.

The python script is pretty straightforward. I use svn library to parse the repository and extract what I need.